# Convert string number with exponent to double value in swift

Tags: swift, xcode

How would I convert a string value with a exponent to a double value that I can use in a calculation

Example:
var newString = "2.9747E+03"

I want to turn that string into a number I can use in formulas.

Comment: What about `Double(newString)` ...?

Comment: The value I get is "nil"

Comment: This might help solve your problem: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/31383

Answer (score 1):

One approach: Use a **NumberFormatter** object.

Those objects have a method `number(from:)` that let you convert a String to an `NSNumber`.
The existing style `.scientific` might meet your needs, or you might need to create a custom format string.

This code works:

```
var numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .scientific
if let value = numberFormatter.number(from:"2.9747E+03")
{
    let dVal = Double(truncating: value)
    print(dVal)
}
```

And outputs

> 2974.7

As pointed out in a now-deleted answer by Dwendel, you could also use the `NSDecimalNumber` initializer that takes a string, and you could then convert that to a `Double.`

That code would look like this:

```
let theNumber = "-6.11104586446241e-01"
let decimalValue = NSDecimalNumber(string: theNumber)
let double = Double(truncating:decimalValue)
print(double)
```

The string-based initializer for NSDecimalNumber would let you convert number strings in scientific notation with less overhead, both in terms of code and memory (supposedly creating a number-formatter is fairly costly.) A `StringFormatter` is more flexible, though, and you could adjust the format it uses if your number strings won't convert directly to a `DecimalNumber`.